# Incorrect Integer Value SQL Error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've already searched and tried to fix error, but I couldn't do that. What's problem inside my code? I'll paste code and error below. As I understand its about type of data. If I make any grammer mistakes, sorry about that.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    INSERT INTO karakter (KullanıcıAdı,uid,Isim,Cinsiyet,Irk,Boy,Kilo,Gün,Ay,Yıl,Güç,Bünye,Dayanıklılık,Çeviklik,Karizma,Zeka,İrade,Odaklanma,Ustalık,Ziraat,İşçilik,Aşçılık,Botanik,Balıkçılık,Dericilik,Marangozluk,Hekimlik,VahşiYaşam,DuvarUstalığı,Camcılık,Demircilik,Avcılık,Şarapçılık,Çekilme,Kalkan,Hançer,Kılıç,Balta,Gürz,Mızrak,Yay,Arbalet)
    VALUES ("$user","$uid","$isim","$cinsiyet","$irk","$boy","$kilo","$gun","$ay","$yil","$Güç","$Bünye","$Dayanıklılık","$Çeviklik","$Karizma","$Zeka","$İrade","$Odaklanma","$Ustalık",'$Ziraat',"$İşçilik","$Aşçılık","$Botanik","$Balıkçılık","$Dericilik","$Marangozluk","$Hekimlik","$VahşiYaşam","$DuvarUstalığı","$Camcılık","$Demircilik","$Avcılık","$Şarapçılık","$Çekilme","$Kalkan","$Hançer","$Kılıç","$Balta","$Gürz","$Mızrak","$Yay","$Arbalet")
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    KullanıcıAdı=VALUES(KullanıcıAdı),
    uid=VALUES(uid),
    Isim=VALUES(Isim),
    Cinsiyet=VALUES(Cinsiyet),
    Irk=VALUES(Irk),
    Boy=VALUES(Boy),
    Kilo=VALUES(Kilo),
    Gün=VALUES(Gün),
    Ay=VALUES(Ay),
    Yıl=VALUES(Yıl),
    Güç=VALUES(Güç),
    Bünye=VALUES(Bünye),
    Dayanıklılık=VALUES(Dayanıklılık),
    Çeviklik=VALUES(Çeviklik),
    Karizma=VALUES(Karizma),
    Zeka=VALUES(Zeka),
    İrade=VALUES(İrade),
    Odaklanma=VALUES(Odaklanma),
    Ustalık=VALUES(Ustalık),
    Ziraat=VALUES(Ziraat),
    İşçilik=VALUES(İşçilik),
    Aşçılık=VALUES(Aşçılık),
    Botanik=VALUES(Botanik)
SQL;
```

The error is:

> Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Ziraat' at row 1

Comment: easy to understand  `you can not pass empty value  to a integer column.`

Comment: so there's a empty variable before that code. am I right?

Comment: means either provide 0 or any other integer value. `''` is string not integer

Comment: okay figured it out. I get it right. it's totally my fault. I couldn't set the variable. anyway thank you. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on error `Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'Ziraat' at row 1`:-

1.Either you didn't set *the corresponding variable with any value which is going to insert in that column*.

2.Or you are sending `''`(empty string) to that column, and it refuses because column is `integer type`.

Solution:- set your corresponding variable of that column, with a correct integer value (0 or >0).

Note:- check and correct yourself.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Please check the `datatype` of the table field `'Ziraat'`.The `integer` field will not accept `' '` as `integer`.`' '` is `string`.You can give `0` or `>0 any value` in place of `' '`.

Comment: Thanks :) I found the problem.